# Solve Simple NSCSF Number Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Getting the error: `-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` at line         `[firstComponentText setString:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];`.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
    for ( float i = 0.0 ; i <= 1000.0 ; i = i + 2.5)
        [pickerArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:i]];

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        if (thePickerView.tag==1)//weight
        {
            [firstComponentText setString:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];
            weightLabel.text = firstComponentText;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `pickerArray` contain `NSNumber` objects? If so, to get an `NSString`, you'll need to use a method like `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` or `-[NSNumber stringValue]`.

If that's the case, try either of the following:

```
[firstComponentText setString:[[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] stringValue]];
```

or

```
[firstComponentText setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]]];
```